# Localização da Foto no Xamarin Multiplataforma

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Gente, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no Xamarin Mutiplataforma que tira fotos e depois deve recuperar estas fotos tiradas e enviar para um Webservice. 
Gostaria de saber como recuperar a foto que foi tirada? Como consigo acessar a galeria de fotos, tanto no Android como no IOS?
Grato,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O acesso ao sistema de arquivos é dependente de plataforma, por isso não tem como acessar diretamente pela API multiplataforma do Xamarin.

Normalmente isso é resolvido via [injeção de dependência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection), você cria uma interface, e em cada projeto específico de plataforma, você implementa e registra no framework de DI que você usa (ou [o do próprio Xamarin](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/), se não estiver usando nenhum), o acesso ao arquivo que você precisa.

[Nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/photo-picker), tem um exemplo que deve ser bem próximo do que você quer.

Comment: Julio, bom dia.O link me ajudou a resolver o problema. Grato pela resposta.